# Who actually handles exceptions thrown in the main method?

Tags: java, exception

If we throw an exception in the method `main` and don't handle it it will work fine. Actually

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    throw new IOException(); //OK
}
```

But Java requires any checked exception to be handled in the program, therefore the `IOException` should be handled. Who actually handles the IOException in that case?

Note, that the Java Language Specification defines the Exception is handled if it enclosed with a try block containing a `catch` clause the type is a supertype of the Exception.

Comment: @KorayTugay What? Your comment seems to be absolutely non-constructive

Comment: Downvoters, could you explain why? I asked about formal explanation of the JVM working princeples

Comment: I am surprised this question was only asked a year ago and no one asked this before. This is definitely a good question to ask. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you haven't taken any special actions to catch the exception yourself, the `ThreadGroup`s default `uncaughtException` is executed.

This is specified in JLS [Chapter 11.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3).

> If no catch clause that can handle an exception can be found, then the current thread (the thread that encountered the exception) is terminated. Before termination, all finally clauses are executed and the uncaught exception is handled according to the following rules:
>
> 1. If the current thread has an uncaught exception handler set, then that handler is executed.
> 2. Otherwise, the method `uncaughtException` is invoked for the `ThreadGroup` that is the parent of the current thread. If the `ThreadGroup` and its parent `ThreadGroups` do not override `uncaughtException`, **then the default handler's `uncaughtException` method is invoked.**

Furthermore the javadoc of [`ThreadGroup.uncaughtException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) reads as follows:

> Called by the Java Virtual Machine when a thread in this thread group stops because of an uncaught exception, and the thread does not have a specific `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` installed.
>
> The `uncaughtException` method of `ThreadGroup` does the following:
>
> - If this thread group has a parent thread group, the `uncaughtException` method of that parent is called with the same two arguments.
> - Otherwise, this method checks to see if there is a default uncaught exception handler installed, and if so, its `uncaughtException` method is called with the same two arguments.
> - Otherwise, this method determines if the `Throwable` argument is an instance of `ThreadDeath`. If so, nothing special is done. Otherwise, a message containing the thread's name, as returned from the thread's `getName` method, and a stack backtrace, using the `Throwable`'s `printStackTrace` method, is printed to the standard error stream.

Comment: So, actually if the exception's not caught by a catch clause, it'll still be handled by the JVM calling that method. That's explain anything.

Comment: If an exception is not caught by a catch clause, the JVM will let the ThreadGroup of the throwing thread (i.e. the thread that runs `main`) handle the exception.

Comment: This is the only in-depth explanation that can be found in the entire internet on Earth.

Answer (score 2):

If the exception is not caught, the thread's or the thread group's uncaught exception handler is invoked, and then the thread terminates.

The JLS [chapter 11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3) states that:

> If no `catch` clause that can handle an exception can be found, then the
>   current thread (the thread that encountered the exception) is
>   terminated. Before termination, all `finally` clauses are executed and
>   the uncaught exception is handled according to the following rules:
>
> If the current thread has an uncaught exception handler set, then that handler is executed.
>
> Otherwise, the method `uncaughtException` is invoked for the `ThreadGroup` that is the parent of the current thread. If the
>   `ThreadGroup` and its parent `ThreadGroup`s do not override
>   `uncaughtException`, then the default handler's `uncaughtException` method
>   is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

JVM itself handles the exceptions thrown from `main()`.

Comment: Why do you think so? Is it mentioned in the Java Specification or Java Virtual Machine Specification?

Comment: I do not remember where it is mentioned. But it is a kind of common knowledge.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a formal explanation of that fact. Just to make sure, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3) chapter doesn't mention it.

Comment: Well, good luck with it. IMHO life is too short to spend it looking for the formal descriptions of well known (or obvious) facts.

Comment: @user3663882, that chapter *does* mention what happens. Keep in mind that the `main` is also executed by a thread (albeit a thread spawned by the VM).

Comment: @AlexR, if you don't find the question interesting enough to dig up a decent answer, then why bother posting?